# Repurpose adjustable standing desk linear actuator for a project on my truck

Tags: ac, dc, linear, actuator

*Disclaimer: fairly limited experience with electrical engineering.*

I'm currently making a deck for my snowmobile that will sit in my truck bed -
a 'Sled deck'. Nice sled decks have telescopic sides so the sides expand to facilitate two snowmobiles side by side. I would like to make the sides telescope out electrically using linear actuators, will be simple to put together and easy to wire into the trailer power in my truck bed.

I have been looking on progressive automation's website and found some actuators that would work and a control panel that will allow presets - having presets is something I never thought of but now really want... however, it's coming in pretty expensive.

It dawned on me that maybe I could repurpose the control panel and actuators from a standing deck (there is one for sale on Facebook marketplace locally for one fourth the price of getting everything new).

However the standing desk has a household AC plug on and I need them to work with DC. Is there any way I could do that?

Alternatively, is there cheaper way anyone knows of setting presets than the $150 control from progressive?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question on how to jury-rig a number of specific items together, which items may be no longer available in near future. Result will be misery unless lots of understanding and data sheets are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’d need to have a close look at the circuitry; it’s quite possible that the actuators run on low-voltage DC and the control circuit certainly will.  If you’re lucky you’ll find that there’s an AC to DC power module, so you could essentially remove that and operate the whole thing from DC (if you’re really lucky it will be 12V).

It’s also possible that the power conversion circuit is built into the control board, in which case you’d need to do some surgery to feed in DC at the right point.  You may need more than one supply voltage, which could get more complicated.

Another approach, which might work well for you, would be to use an inverter to generate AC and then run from that.

Be aware though that a desk is designed for indoor use, so consider what will happen when it gets wet.

Good luck!

Comment: cheers Frog. if the desk had AC to DC module that would be too easy.. is there an easy way to identity that? I thought about an inverter but more trouble than its worth. the deck mostly seals off the truck bed form the elements so it will have very little exposure to moisture or any sort of weather. i was also planning on 3d printing housing for everything to keep it tidy and ever drier.

Comment: The most obvious case is where you have a ‘wall wart’, which will have printed on it the output voltage and current.  Failing that you may find that the AC plug goes to a box somewhere that has just the AC in and one other cable coming out.  If the AC goes directly into the control box then it’s not so straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, im going to check it out and see if i can make it work. cheers for your input. ill let you know if i can get it to work